# How to send alert message on specific day and time on android?

Tags: android

I am new to android. Could anyone please tell me how can I send alert message on specific day and time? For example: I have to display an alert message at 9:00 am every friday. How can I do it?

Comment: I have the following code which displayed a notification on every 10 seconds difference. I have no idea how can i set the notification for specific date and time.

Comment: Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                  calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                  calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);

 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                   am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);

Comment: why down vote? voting without comment?

Answer (score 1):

I think [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is what you are looking for.